# Accessing dom element in A-Frame

Tags: javascript, dom, aframe

How can I access the dom element in A-Frame in this image gallery: [Glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/plain-curve?path=index.html:1:0)?

I placed one button to change the scene but the button is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting elements is not something specific to A-Frame. As I can see in your example everything works but you're not emitting the `click` event on the correct entity:

```
var cubeEntity = document.querySelector('#cube');
```

should be:

```
var cubeEntity = document.querySelector('#cube .link');
```

Fixed demo:

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/shiny-pancreas?path=index.html:88:0

Comment: Thanks Diego Marcos